# Evaluate $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\arctan\frac{\sqrt{2}\cos 3x}{(3+2\cos 2x)\sqrt{\cos 2x}}{\rm d}x$.

Tags: definite-integrals

## Problem

Evaluate $$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\arctan\frac{\sqrt{2}\cos 3x}{(3+2\cos 2x)\sqrt{\cos 2x}}{\rm d}x.$$

The integrand is complicated. [AlphaWolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B4%7D%7D%5Carctan%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%5Ccos%203x%7D%7B(3%2B2%5Ccos%202x)%5Csqrt%7B%5Ccos%202x%7D%7D%20dx) outputs the result is zero. If we consider making a subsitution, let $x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}-u$, then
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\arctan\frac{\sqrt{2}\cos 3x}{(3+2\cos 2x)\sqrt{\cos 2x}}{\rm d}x=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\arctan\frac{\sqrt{2}\cos\left(3u+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)}{(3+2\sin 2u)\sqrt{\sin 2x}}{\rm d}u,$$
which seems to be helpless.